# Provider Class not found in In ProviderRepository.php line 208

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have create a simple Laravel Package and pushed it on Github

https://github.com/akshaykhale1992/model-notes

and Published the Package on Packagist

https://packagist.org/packages/akshaykhale1992/model-note

I tried to install it in my laravel application, it pulled the package from Github but the package installation was not successful.

Below is the Error that is returned by composer command

```
root@root.com:~/$ composer require akshaykhale1992/model-note
Using version dev-master for akshaykhale1992/model-note
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing akshaykhale1992/model-note (dev-master 5543914): Cloning 554391487e from cache
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'AkshayKhale1992\ModelNote\ModelNoteProvider' not found  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Terminal Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I think you need to specify an autoload path. Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: in which file? @apokryfos

Comment: `composer.json` add an entry to link your root namespace (i.e. `AkashayKhale1992` to a physical path i.e. `src`)

Comment: It worked, thanks, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question @apokryfos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for composer to properly generate the autoload file for your package (as well as all packages) it needs to know where to find the namespaces and files that are referenced. This is done via the [`autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) entry in `composer.json`

In your case, since you are already following the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard you need something like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AkshayKhale1992\\ModelNote\\": "src/"
    }
}
```